# apacheds-2.0.0-M17 log file

Tags: apacheds

```
tail -f /var/lib/apacheds-2.0.0-M17/default/log/apacheds.log
```

nothing is coming out. Any idea's ?. Already done some modification in log4j.properties but still no luck.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Find it. Must changed manually in log4j.properties.